# Chances of hiding a werewolf tail?

Tags: werewolf

Werewolves in my setting turn during full moons. They appear very wolf-like aside from modified hips, legs, arms and neck allowing for a bipedal stance in addition to the quadrupedal stance.

Mass redistribution occurs when forming the tail; no mass is added. One werewolf had their tail severed by an axe right before daylight, clean swing right at the base. They turned back moments after. Reattachment of the tail to the base of the back was necessary for keeping it alive until the next full moon when it will be reabsorbed. The werewolf in question has their tail in human form till then.

Could it be successfully hidden from view or otherwise explained?

EDIT:The world is a planet very similar to modern day earth, with two major moons. both at low inclines ~2°,5° and orbiting at 1,4 orbital resonance (7.25 and 29 local days respectively) total eclipses happen far more frequently than on Earth.
total Solar and total Lunar eclipses flip the physical and mental states of a werewolf respectively. e.g. werewolf mental control switches to human during full moon this they'd be in control during full moons. day state stay as human.
direct contact with full lunar light when direct sun light is below 500lux triggers transformation.
Locking a werewolf away, from direct sunlight, during a full moon until a solar eclipse will result in their full moon state being locked physically as a human. conversely exposing them from sunlight directly, avoiding the brighter stage of the full moon, to a total lunar eclipse will result in their day state being stuck as a wolf.

The biology stays the same,  e.g. blood will remain human O- not change to DEA (dog blood). War being fought between the neighboring countries needs more blood supply.
Being discovered would result in the character being kidnapped (involuntary conscription) and converted semi permanently into a physical and possibly mental wolf for use as a military dog substitute. Werewolves are compatible with human soldiers as blood bags, live longer than a dog, capable of incognito spying, loyalty can be beaten in by muzzling or exposure to total lunar eclipse, dehumanizing treatment.

Comment: [Related art](https://dilbert.com/strip/1990-07-08) for social effects of having tails.

Comment: Thanks, Nathaniel. I've retracted my vote. We appreciate you working with the community!

Comment: Male or female? floofy dresses could hide a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**She's got a ponytail.  She's got a ponytail.  She's got a P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-Ponytail!**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDg6-v9V8lo

[image: pony tails]

That's right.  Do not watch this video unless you are ready for these cartoon girl birds to carve a new groove in your brain, from which they will continue to play this song, forever.

Fortunately your lycanthrope character had long flowing locks to start with and mixing her severed tail in there just fills it out and looks great.  Sort of a hair extensions thing.  It would not surprise me if keeping her tail stuck to the back of her head becomes a regular habit, because she also likes how the mass redistribution to make the tail leaves her pants a little less snug.

Comment: Seriously? Lol.

Comment: Well tell everyone then, why don't you?

Comment: @Wilk Why it's not possible to upvote an answer more than once? ^.^ Thumbs up! My toddler son would have Badanamu played many times a day. I will go to my grave with this song still echoing in my head.

Comment: Oh, this is precious. Connect the tail to the unlucky's head....

Comment: Definitely wouldn't be noticed by any military personnel. I really like this answer.

Comment: Let's just take a second to appreciate the like:dislike ratio of that video.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: There are a bunch of ways you can go about hiding or explaining a werewolf tail. You can wear extra long backpacks that extend to your waist, and stick your tail inside, that could work. But the most foolproof way is to go to a cosplay festival and pretend to be a furry, you would blend right in, and no one will ask any questions.

If your werewolf is smart it'll be fine.

Comment: Smart enough not to request the surgeon reattach it to their head?

Comment: The surgeon would be hard-pressed to do that for them, and plus didnt they regenerate the tail?

Comment: provided it's still attached. I wanted to start with a easy question, seems I didn't do enough research myself to get to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Put on a long, flowing skirt, and keep the tail in the skirt.